# DXL script to copy object with pictures combined with strings

Tags: image, ibm-doors

I wrote a dxl-script that reads out certain requirements in one module and place a new objct with some of its data in another module. Everything works just fine until there are pictures included. If there is a picture in the object heading and I want to copy this heading into another object, it simply fills in the text and skips the picture. Is there a way to cope with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With "picture" do you mean a DOORS picture or an OLE Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `o1` is the source object with an "image" in its `Object Text`, while, `o2` is the target object.
Let's copy all plain text, rich text and images(ole) from `o1."Object text"` to `o2."Object Text"`:

```
Object o1, o2 
string s = richTextWithOle(o1."Object Text") 
o2."Object Text" = richText (s)
```

Answer (score 0):

OLE Objects should be transferred to the destination attributes when you use the perm `set (newObject.attrname, oldObject.attrname)`